# display search result using ajax in a div

Tags: php, ajax, html, cordova

hello i have built a multi  search form using php, basically this search form queries from a particular date to another, which i have gotten to work perfectly,
using this codes

search.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="report_advanced.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1"> 
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="inputagent name"><span class="asasa">*</span> Advanced Search:</label>
<div class="controls">
  <input type="text" name="from" value="" size="32" id="inputDate" placeholder="From" /><br /><br />
  <input type="text" name="to" value="" size="32" id="inputDatess" placeholder="To" />

  </div>
</div>

<p align="center">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" value="Search" /></p>

    </form>
```

and

report_advanced.php

```
mysql_select_db($database_kbl, $kbl);
$query_cert = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE `Start_Date`  BETWEEN %s AND %s ", 
GetSQLValueString($colname_cert, "text"),GetSQLValueString($colname2_cert, "text"));
$query_limit_cert = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_cert, $startRow_cert, $maxRows_cert);
$cert = mysql_query($query_limit_cert, $kbl) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cert = mysql_fetch_assoc($cert);


<table width="60%" class="table table-bordered" id="table"></span> 
  <tr class="success">

    <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Insured Name</td>
    <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Telephone No</td>
     <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Policy Number</td>
     <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Car Make</td>
     <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Model</td>

    <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Registeration Number</td>
    <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Amount</td>
<td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Start Date</td>
 <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%">Expiry Date</td>

  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr  class="success" style="text-transform:capitalize;font-size:16px">
    <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Insured_Name']; ?></td>
    <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Telephone']; ?></td>
     <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Policy_Number']; ?></td>
       <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Make_Of_Car']; ?></td>
        <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Model']; ?></td>


      <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Registeration_Number']; ?></td>
       <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Premium']; ?></td>
            <td style="color:#FFF" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Start_Date']; ?> </td>
             <td style="color:#FFF; font-size:14px" width="10%"><?php echo $row_cert['Expiry_Date']; ?></td>


  <?php } while ($row_cert = mysql_fetch_assoc($cert)); ?> </table>
    <?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
```

but now i want to implement this same type of functionality in a mobile app, using phonegap, and i intend to make ajax requests using the snippets i have posted and display in a div, since php cannot be run in phonegap,

but i dont know how o go about this, i have done some searchin online but havent seen what i am lookin 4.

most especially because i want to use the same code i have used in my web project for this app by makin an ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Simply, what you do is just make another `http ajax` request from phonegap to the same endpoint to your server, get the response and reload it in the div.

i.e

```
$.get(url_to_endpoint, function(data){
    // do reloading of your div
});
```

this is can be done using `jquerymobile` library easily or depends how you do http requests from your phonegap.